# Adding an existing AMI to a new VPC with Amazon Services

Tags: vpn, amazon-ec2

As the title. I have just created a new VPC but it seems i can only launch new instances into the VPC?

Am I missing something?

w://

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, you need to re-launch all your instances inside the VPC.
I could not find a way to migrate existing instances into the VPC.